# Unable to Connect to PowerDesigner through java

Tags: java, eclipse, com, powerdesigner, ole-automation

I have a requirement to automate the process of connecting to PowerDesigner through java to extract the models from repository. I have used the OLE Automation JavaProxy document to configure the process.

when trying to run, I'm getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM.CoCreateInstance(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/ole/win32/GUID;IILorg/eclipse/swt/internal/ole/win32/GUID;[I)I
> at
> com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdCommon.Application.start(Application.java:57)
> at
> com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdCommon.Application.(Application.java:31)
> at
> com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdCommon.Application.getInstance(Application.java:42)
> at OOM.src.createOOM.CreateOOM.CreateAndDisplayOOM(CreateOOM.java:37)
> at OOM.src.createOOM.CreateOOM.main(CreateOOM.java:28)

**Versions:**

- PowerDesigner - 16.5.5.0
- Eclipse 4.18

**Supporting Jars:**

- pdj2com_16.5.5.jar
- org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.115.100.v20201202-1103.jar

**The above issue is resolved Thanks!**

Now i'm facing trouble connecting again with the below issue.

org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Action can not be performed. result = -2137456383 (com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.com.COMException:  COM Failure [HRESULT: 0x80990101])
at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(OLE.java:345)
at com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.com.COMException.raiseOnFail(COMException.java:83)
at com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.com.IDispatchEx.raisingInvoke(IDispatchEx.java:231)
at com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdCommon.IApplication.CreateModel(IApplication.java:84)
at OOM.src.createOOM.CreateOOM.createOOM(CreateOOM.java:68)
at OOM.src.createOOM.CreateOOM.CreateAndDisplayOOM(CreateOOM.java:42)
at OOM.src.createOOM.CreateOOM.main(CreateOOM.java:28)
Caused by: com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.com.COMException:  COM Failure [HRESULT: 0x80990101]
at com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.com.COMException.raiseOnFail(COMException.java:88)
... 5 more
Is there anything else to add to the code to connect?

I am not able to find any solution online. Kindly help me figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're just trying to use the sample code from JavaProxy.doc?

Comment: Yes, @Pascal. Once im able to connect and build a model i will have to customise

Answer (score 1):

The swt.win.win32.x86_64 jar is for 64-bit, so I assume you're using a 64-bit Java.

In my case, the pdj2com jar is named something like **pdj2com_16.N.Nx64.jar** for the 64-bit version. pdj2com_16.N.N.jar is the name of the 32-bit version.

Comment: This did help in resolving, Thanks so much!

Comment: i have added another error that is preventing me from connecting or creating a model in power designer, Can you kindly take a look at it and suggest.